# Unexpected FullSimplify results

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have just started using Mathematica and I am having a hard time understanding the results from `FullSimplify`. Please see examples bellow:

```
FullSimplify[(0.5*H + R), (0.5*H + R) == p]
FullSimplify[(H + R + T), (H + R + T) == 1]
FullSimplify[(0.5*H + R)*(H + R + T), (0.5*H + R) == p && (H + R + T) == 1]
```

I get the following results:

> ```
> p
> 1
> 0.5 (1 + R - T)
> ```

My questions is: Why the last expression does not output `p` (or `p*1`)?

Comment: Seems like a bug to me... The output isn't even correct.

Comment: @JungHwanMin Why do you say the output is incorrect? Consider `(0.5*H + R)*(H + R + T) /. H -> 1 - R - T // Factor`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 You're right... I somehow had a lingering definition for `p`

Comment: Try substituting **x** for **p**, then repeat your evaluation. The answer this time will be **x**. This behavior is not isolated to `FullSimplify`. See Question [#95374](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95374/evaluating-two-equivalent-integrals-apparently-gives-two-different-results/95379#95379 "evaluating-two-equivalent-integrals-apparently-gives-two-different-results") for how canonical order of symbols can affect the results of `Integrate`.

Comment: Also check out @Jens answer to Question [17926](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17926/why-does-simplify-ignore-an-assumption "Why does Simplify ignore an assumption").