# Symbolic Integration gives different results by changing the constants. Is it a bug?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, symbolic

**Problem existing in Version 10.4.1 or earlier and persisting through Version 11.3.0 and fixed in Version 13.0 or earlier**

I have the following integral (I know it could be simplified, but this particular form is important for the question)
$$ 
\int_0^\pi \frac{ \Delta p^2 (1-F) \sin^2(\theta -\theta_r+ \Omega\tau )}{\pi  \left(1-\Delta p^2 \cos ^2(\theta -\theta_r+ \Omega\tau )\right)} \mathrm{d} \theta.
$$
I have Mathematica 11.0.1.0 on Ubuntu 16.04 (but I tried on a Mac as well with the same version). If I start a fresh kernel and without assuming anything I compute the integral in the following way:

```
Integrate[1/π (Δp^2 Sin[Ω τ + θ- θr]^2 (1-F))/(1 - Δp^2 Cos[Ω τ + θ - θr]^2),{θ,0,π}]
```

I get:

```
(* 1 - F *)
```

While, if I use $\Omega \tau = a $ in the following way

```
Integrate[1/π (Δp^2 Sin[a + θ- θr]^2 (1-F))/(1 - Δp^2 Cos[a + θ - θr]^2),{θ,0,π}]
```

I get

```
(* ConditionalExpression[(-1 + F) (-1 + Sqrt[1/(1 - Δp^2)] - Δp^2 Sqrt[1/
   (1 - Δp^2)]),Im[θr] == Im[a] && -(π/2) + Re[a] <= Re[θr] <= π/2 + Re[a]] *)
```

Apart from the result, it is problematic that just by giving a different name to a constant I get different results. Is this a bug?

Now, regarding the result, this is integral can also be done by hand... anyway one can easily see that the first one is wrong because the result obviously has to depend on $\Delta p$, since for $\Delta p = 0$ everything is zero...

Does anybody have a clue?

Comment: I tried on a friend's mathematica 10 and the result is 1-F in both cases... it is the wrong result, but at least it's consistent!

Comment: I can reproduce the strange behavior, it looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Sorry i edited the code but forget to put the  Ω τ to a in the cos. And i cannot edit this again.

Comment: Don't worry, I fixed it... I'll try to write to Wolfram Support I guess...

Comment: related, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/95374/2079

Comment: Is `-1 < Δp < 1` ?  If so, is the correct answer `(-1 + F) (-1 + Sqrt[1 - Δp^2])`?

Comment: @bbgodfrey yes that's the correct result, it's the same it gives me in the second solution (not properly simplified). While it's not nice that it doesn't get the right solution, I am more disturbed by the fact the two seemingly identical computations yield different results...

Comment: I agree.  I tried various options to obtain the correct result but without success.  It certainly looks like a bug.  In fact, some of the conditions that `DSolve` returns when using `a` instead of `Ω τ` even seem unnecessary.  Do you plan to report all this to Wolfram, Inc?

Comment: The underlying integral is similar to the one in http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48113/bug-in-mathematica-analytic-integratione

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Great! I see that the bug has been fixed, I will try Mathematica 13.0 as soon as possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both values seem to be correct, depending on the parameters; however, the dependence on the parameters is not correctly expressed in the `ConditionalExpression` result.  It may be that the OP has in mind a real integral, but *Mathematica*, by default, treats the parameters as complex numbers.  By a standard application of the Residue Theorem, an integral of the form $(1/2\pi)\int_0^{2\pi} R(\cos t,\sin t)\,dt$, where $R(x,y)$ is a rational function, is equal to the sum of the residues of
$$
{1\over z}\cdot R\left({z+z^-1 \over 2},{z-z^-1 \over 2i}\right)
$$
over the poles in $|z|<1$.
The OP's integral is of this form ($2\theta=t$):
$$ 
\int_0^\pi \frac{ \Delta p^2 (1-F) \sin^2(\theta -\theta_r+ \Omega\tau )}{\pi  \left(1-\Delta p^2 \cos ^2(\theta -\theta_r+ \Omega\tau )\right)} \; d\theta
=
\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{ \Delta p^2 (1-F) \sin^2(t/2-t_0)}{2\pi  \left(1-\Delta p^2 \cos ^2(t/2-t_0)\right)} \;dt
$$
$$ 
\qquad=
{1\over2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\Delta p^2 (1-F) (\sin t \sin
   2 {t_0}+\cos t \cos 2
   {t_0}-1)}{\left({\Delta
   p}^2+{\Delta p}^2 \sin t \sin 2
   {t_0}+{\Delta p}^2 \cos t \cos 2
   {t_0}-2\right)} \;dt
$$

Here is are plots of the numerical integration for an imaginary value of $t_0$ (code below):

> [image: Mathematica graphics]
>
> *Fig. 1. Plots of the integral computed with `NIntegrate[]` for $\Delta p=x+i\,y$, $F=0$, $t_0=0.1i$; the middle plot shows that the integral equals $1-F = 1$ outside a figure-eight region (where all the poles are inside the unit disk).*

Here is an implementation of the above idea:

```
op = 1/π (Δp^2 Sin[Ω τ + θ - θr]^2 (1 - F))/(1 - Δp^2 Cos[Ω τ + θ - θr]^2) /. 
    {θr -> t0 + Ω τ, θ -> t/2};
integrand = op/2 // TrigReduce // TrigExpand // 
   Simplify[#,                 (* Complexity function unwanted trig forms *)
     ComplexityFunction -> (LeafCount[#] + 
         1000 Count[#, 
           Sin[1/2 (t - 2 t0)] | Sin[t/2 - t0] | Cos[t - 2 t0], 
           Infinity] &)] &;

intz = Block[{F = 0},
     integrand
     ] /. {Sin[t] -> (z - 1/z)/(2 I), Cos[t] -> (z + 1/z)/2} // Simplify;
poles = Solve[z*Denominator[intz] == 0, z] // Simplify;
residues = Residue[1/z*intz, {z, z /. #}] & /@ poles // FullSimplify;

(* the value of the integral *)
val = 2 Pi*residues.UnitStep[1 - Abs[z /. poles]] // PiecewiseExpand // FullSimplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The third condition cannot happen, but *Mathematica* does not figure that out. (The two distinct absolute values are reciprocals of each other, and the greater one has a minimum value of `1`. This implies the first two pieces cover all cases. But that's difficult to compute.)

> [image: Mathematica graphics]
>
> *Fig. 2. Plots of the symbolic value `val` of the integral for $\Delta p=x+i\,y$, $F=0$, $t_0=0.1i$; the middle plot show that the integral equals $1-F = 1$ outside a figure-eight region (where all the poles are inside the unit disk).*

***Remark on the computational issue.***
One reason for the different results that the OP experiences is probably the increase in complexity of using a product of constants `Ω τ` over a single constant `a`. I think this is worth emphasizing: *Mathematica* will try to reduce the conditions and perhaps tries to break down the conditions into terms involving the parts of `Ω` and `τ` separately.  This might lead to different results than with a simpler `a`.
(It does not, however, explain the incorrectness in the result.)
Sometimes, with symbolics it pays to simplify the parameters, such replacing `Ω τ` by `a`, or indeed both terms `Ω τ - θr` by `t0`.  They can then be substituted back at the end of the computation.

---

*Code for figure 1:*

```
Block[{Δp = x + I y, t0 = 0 + t1 I, t1 = 0.1, F = 0},
  iplotAbs = Plot3D[
     Abs@NIntegrate[
       1/π (Δp^2 Sin[t - t0]^2 (1 - F))/(1 - Δp^2 Cos[t - t0]^2),
       {t, 0, π}, Method -> "Trapezoidal", PrecisionGoal -> 4, 
       AccuracyGoal -> 4, MaxRecursion -> 20],
     {x, -1.04/t1, 1.04/t1}, {y, -1.04/t1, 1.04/t1}, 
     MaxRecursion -> 3, PlotLabel -> "Modulus of integral", 
     MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, AxesLabel -> {x, y}
     ];
  ] // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {141.737, Null}  *)

Block[{Δp = x + I y, t0 = 0 + t1 I, t1 = 0.1, F = 0},
  iplotArg = Plot3D[
     Arg@NIntegrate[
       1/π (Δp^2 Sin[t - t0]^2 (1 - F))/(1 - Δp^2 Cos[t - t0]^2),
       {t, 0, π}, Method -> "Trapezoidal", PrecisionGoal -> 4, 
       AccuracyGoal -> 4, MaxRecursion -> 20],
     {x, -1.04/t1, 1.04/t1}, {y, -1.04/t1, 1.04/t1}, 
     MaxRecursion -> 3, AxesLabel -> {x, y}, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, 
     PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> "Argument of integral"
     ];
  ] // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {145.414, Null}  *)

GraphicsRow[{iplotAbs, 
  Show[iplotAbs, PlotRange -> {0.8, 1.2}, ViewPoint -> {0, 3.5, 0.7}], 
  iplotArg}, ImageSize -> 600]
```

*Code for Figure 2:*

```
Block[{Δp = x + I y, t0 = 0 + t1 I, t1 = 0.1, F = 0},
 GraphicsRow[
  Plot3D[
     #[val],
     {x, -1.04/t1, 1.04/t1}, {y, -1.04/t1, 1.04/t1}, 
     MaxRecursion -> 3, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, ImageSize -> 300, 
     AxesLabel -> {x, y}, PlotLabel -> #["val"], 
     Exclusions -> {Automatic, {x == 0, # === Arg}}
     ] & /@
   {Abs, Arg}, ImageSize -> 600
  ]
 ]
```

Comment: +1 just for the nice looking plots, as the math is too hard for me to follow :)

Comment: Thank you for the interesting and deep answer... So as far I understand I should fill a bug report to wolfram for the incorrect integral and not for the inconsistency, because it might be expected?

Comment: Yes, please file a bug report.  From the comments to [this older, similar problem](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48113/bug-in-mathematica-analytic-integratione), it seems that getting a general-purpose algorithm to do this right is harder to get right than to solve a single instance.  But each example probably helps them find improvements.

Answer (score 3):

With suitable `Assumptions`, the two formulations give equivalent results:

```
Integrate[1/π (Δp^2 Sin[Ω τ + θ - θr]^2 (1 - F))/(1 - Δp^2 Cos[Ω τ + θ - θr]^2), 
    {θ, 0, π}, Assumptions -> -1 < Δp < 1 && 0 < θr < π && 0 < Ω τ < π]
(* ConditionalExpression[(-1 + F) (-1 + 2 Sqrt[1 - Δp^2]), π + 2 θr < 2 τ Ω] *)

Integrate[1/π (Δp^2 Sin[a + θ - θr]^2 (1 - F))/(1 - Δp^2 Cos[a + θ - θr] 2), 
    {θ, 0, π}, Assumptions -> -1 < Δp < 1 && 0 < θr < π && 0 < a < π]    
(* ConditionalExpression[(-1 + F) (-1 + 2 Sqrt[1 - Δp^2]), 2 a > π + 2 θr] *)
```

Both now are wrong!  The correct solution is

```
Integrate[1/π (Δp^2 Sin[θ]^2 (1 - F))/(1 - Δp^2 Cos[θ]^2), {θ, 0, π}, 
    Assumptions -> -1 < Δp < 1]
(* (-1 + F) (-1 + Sqrt[1 - Δp^2]) *)
```

Setting `Ω τ - θr` to zero is valid, because the integrand is periodic with period `Pi`.  Incidentally, setting only `Ω τ` to zero also gives the correct result, although with an extraneous condition.

```
Integrate[1/π (Δp^2 Sin[θ - θr]^2 (1 - F))/(1 - Δp^2 Cos[θ - θr]^2), {θ, 0, π}, 
    Assumptions -> -1 < Δp < 1 && 0 < θr < π]
(* ConditionalExpression[(-1 + F) (-1 + Sqrt[1 - Δp^2]), 2 θr < π] *)
```

Clearly, the strange behavior exhibited here and in the question represents one or more bugs.

These results were obtained with

```
$Version
(* "10.4.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (April 11, 2016)" *)
```

and

```
(* "11.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (September 11, 2017)" *)
```

Incidentally, the newer version of Mathematica does not reproduce the `ConditionalExpression` in the question, instead giving,

```
(* ConditionalExpression[-I (-1 + F) (-I + Sqrt[-1 + Δp^2] + 2 Sqrt[-1 + Δp^2]
   Floor[Arg[-1 + Δp^2]/(4 π)]), 
   Im[a] == Im[θr] && -(π/2) + Re[a] <= Re[θr] <= π/2 + Re[a]] *)
```

**Addendum**

Identical behavior persists for

```
(* "11.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)" *)
```

except that it fails in a different way to reproduce the `ConditionalExpression` in the question, instead giving,

```
ConditionalExpression[1 - F, C[1] ∈ Integers && 
    Im[a] == Im[θr] && -(π/2) <= π C[1] - Re[a] + Re[θr] <= π/2]
```

Comment: Ok thank you for investigating this problem in detail. I never reported a bug to Wolfram, but it's clear that it might good a be idea to do so. I was not even aware that 11.1 came out by the way.

Comment: Things seem to get wild in MMA 11.2.0 for the second expression in your answer. `Integrate[1/π (Δp^2 Sin[a + θ - θr]^2 (1 - F))/(1 - Δp^2 Cos[a + θ - θr] 2), {θ, 0, π}, Assumptions -> -1 < Δp < 1 && 0 < θr < π && 0 < a < π]` returns a very complicated ConditionalExpression with Cot, Tan and Log in it...

Comment: @user58955  Thanks, for checking whether this bug persisted.  I shall take a close look at the matter next week, when I have time.

Comment: @user58955  The expression in your comment is missing `^`: `Cos[a + θ - θr] 2` should be `Cos[a + θ - θr]^2`.  In general, I find no difference between 11.1 and 11.2.